# How do I send an email from the localhost with Swiftmailer and Yii?

Tags: php, yii, yii2, swiftmailer

When I try to send a mail, I'm getting this error message from my mail server:

> Swift_TransportException
>   Expected response code 250 but got code "501", with message "501 5.5.2 <[::1]>: Helo command rejected: invalid ip address"

In the debug bar, I see the SERVER_ADDR is set to ::1, but I can find no way to change it. I commented the ::1 value in `hosts`, leaving 127.0.0.1 and restarted Apache, but it didn't help.

Hipster text to get around Stack Overflow bug https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289410/bug-cannot-submit-question-with-answer

> 3 wolf moon retro jean shorts chambray sustainable roof party. Shoreditch vegan artisan Helvetica. Tattooed Codeply Echo Park Godard kogi, next level irony ennui twee squid fap selvage. Meggings 
>   flannel Brooklyn literally small batch, mumblecore PBR try-hard kale chips. Brooklyn vinyl lumbersexual bicycle rights, viral 
>   fap cronut leggings squid chillwave pickled gentrify mustache. 3 wolf moon hashtag church-key Odd Future. Austin messenger bag normcore, 
>   Helvetica Williamsburg sartorial tote bag distillery Portland before they sold out gastropub taxidermy Vice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [Swiftmailer SMTP transport rejecting local IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362417/swiftmailer-smtp-transport-rejecting-local-ip-address),

```
        'transport' => [
          'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
          ...
          'encryption' => 'tls',
          'localDomain' => '[127.0.0.1]',
        ],
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-swiftmailer-mailer.html (but `localDomain` is not documented!)